# Parse text position vector to floats

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a .txt file that contains lines in this format:

```
{"Position":[81.2305,4.05698,9.14912]}
```

Because I have lots of other lines that start with an open bracket and a name enclosed in quotes followed by a semi-colon, I have split the line into two like this:

```
[ '{"Position":', '[81.2305,4.05698,9.14912]}' ]
```

I would like to parse the second string into a list of 3 floats. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data looks like JSON, so you can use the built-in JSON module:

```
import json

pos = [] # list of (x,y,z)

with open('t.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        # skip blank lines (add other cases as needed)
        if not line.strip():
            continue

        item = json.loads(line)
        if "Position" in item:
            pos.append(item["Position"])

print(pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re    
re.sub(r':',':#',s).split('#')
```